# JavaScript: what is the relationship between processor speed and code speed?

Tags: javascript, performance, benchmarking

I would hope that the faster my processor is, the faster my code would run.

I can measure code to the millisecond precision using.

```
new Date.getTime()
```

What is the correlation between the two?

How can I expect this to relate to say a processor running at 3.2 GHz.

Can anyone quantify this relationship even if it is a very rough estimate?

```
// start_time

run some simple code to be timed.

// end_time
```

Comment: Does your computer's clock run faster if you have a faster processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [EDIT: **CPU**]clock time that gets allotted to a JS script is determined by a number of factors, including:

- browser/version
- OS
- current power state

A demonstration of this can be seen in Windows 8's Advanced Power Options menu. Expand the Internet Explorer node and you'll notice that the entry below is for `JavaScript timer frequency`. That's exactly what you think it is -- a setting which controls how often the JS clock 'ticks'. The more ticks in a second, the more often the JS engine gets to execute code, the more code executed, the more power it takes.

So to answer your question:
Yes, in the very general sense processor clock speed can determine how fast a particular JS runs, but it would be a mistake to assume that it is a straight-forward correlation.

EDIT (more info):
I can't dig a link but I'll update here if I find it. Using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, the smallest unit of time you can pass into those methods that will actually be honored is 100(ms). It's possible to have higher frequencies than that, but 100ms is all that is guaranteed

I found something close to what I was thinking in this article:
http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Essentially, in JavaScript timers operated on a queued basis -- you can call `setTimeout(fn, 10)`, and your request will be queued to execute after 10ms, but that doesn't mean that it *will* get executed after that amount of time, just that it's queued to do so. If you measure the difference between expected and actual (above a threshold, probably 100ms) you could gather offset data to calculate the resulting frequency (or 'clock speed') the script is running at. See [this article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/07/How-to-measure-browser-graphics-performance) for an example of benchmarking JS in more precise ways

From that second article, we see that the minimum timeout you can get is 4ms:

> Using setTimeout for measuring graphics performance is another bad idea. The setTimeout interval is capped to 4 ms in browsers, so the most you can get out of it is 250 FPS. Historically, browsers had different minimum intervals, so you might have had a very broken trivial draw benchmark that showed browser A running at 250 FPS (4 ms min interval) and browser B running at 100 FPS (10 ms min interval). Clearly A is faster! Not! It could well be that B ran the draw code faster than A, say A took 3 ms and B took 1 ms. Doesn’t affect the FPS, as the draw time is less than the minimum setTimeout interval. And if the browser renders asynchronously, all bets are off. Don’t use setTimeout unless you know what you’re doing.

Comment: the option doesn't list any specific frequencies, but I'd guess that it would operate as some sort of factor of overall cpu clock speed. The base unit of measurement could be Hz, operations/second (or flops if you're just looking at a subset), % clock time vs. overall cpu time, etc

Comment: that's not something readily quantifiable since there are too many factors involved... the easy answer is "however much it requests and the system is able to fulfill"

Comment: I'm sorry - I was saying it does not have any specific number -- see my edit about `setTimeout`

Comment: I see there only two options - http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/159269-internet-explorer-javascript-timer-frequency-power-plan-settings.html